# Help crafting equation - How to calculate all invalid combinations

Tags: combinations, puzzle

This is related to a Programming puzzle that I am working on.

[image]

Without the restriction that three posts cannot be the same color in a row this problem is trivial.

`combinations(n, k) = k ^ n;`

Given that observation, my intuition to solving the problem was to subtract out invalid combinations from all combinations leaving me with the answer for all valid combinations.

**TL;DR;**

I'd like help crafting an equation such that invalidCombinations(n, k) returns the total number of invalid combinations. Where invalid means any one item is repeated three times in a row.

**Context on what I've tried**

To start to craft an equation for invalidCombinations(n) I looked at a sample data set when k=2

```
k = 2
invalidCombinations(1) = 0
invalidCombinations(2) = 0
invalidCombinations(3) = 2 (e.g. 111 & 222)
invalidCombinations(4) = 6 (e.g. 1111 & 2111 & 1112 & 2222 & 1222 & 2221)
invalidCombinations(5) = 16
invalidCombinations(6) = 38
```

After a bit of thinking I observed that

`invalidCombinations(n) = (k ^ (n - 2)) + invalidCombinations(n - 1) + invalidCombinations(n - 2);`

Sure enough when I test

I get the correct answer for k = 2. Hooray...

Except my equation falls apart when I look at k = 3.

My Output:

```
k = 3
invalidCombinations(1) = 0;
invalidCombinations(2) = 0;
invalidCombinations(3) = 3;
invalidCombinations(4) = 12;
invalidCombinations(5) = 42;
```

Expected:

```
k = 3
invalidCombinations(1) = 0;
invalidCombinations(2) = 0;
invalidCombinations(3) = 3;
invalidCombinations(4) = 15;
invalidCombinations(5) = 63;
```

The jump from invalidCombinations(3) to invalidCombinations(4) is an interesting one.
the three invalid combinations for

```
invalidCombinations(3)
111
222
333
```

For invalidCombinations(4) you can simply add 1,2,3 to the front or to the end of the already invalid combination. Then remove the duplicate

```
invalidCombinations(4)
combinations based on (111)
1111
2111
3111
1111 (duplicate)
1112
1113

Repeat for 222
1222
2222
...

Repeat for 3333
1333
2333
3333
...

invalidCombinations(4) = 15
```

My intuition tells me that 1111, 2222, and 3333 are just continuations of the pattern identified in invalidCombinations(3). So I think the answer is still `invalidCombinations(n) = {SOMETHING} + invalidCombinations(n - 1) + invalidCombinations(n - 2)`

But after thinking on this one a bit more I am struggling to come up with an equation that solves invalid combos for all possible values of k. I went ahead and looked at the solution provided in the problem and it took a slightly different approach by iteratively solving all valid routes to arrive at an answer. (e.g. no calculation for total routes or invalid routes).

While I understand the provided answer and it might be cleaner than what I was intending to do, I'd like to know if my intuition was bad on this one, is there an equation that I just am not landing on? Or does the equation I am looking for end up being too gnarly?

Appreciate any insights folks might have!

Comment: Your link requires a subscription. Can you paste the problem into your post?

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks for the heads up. Problem updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to count invalid combinations is, ironically, to count valid ones and subtract from $k^n$.

Let

- $B_n$ be the number of valid ways to paint the fence, such that the last two fenceposts have the same colour.
- $A_n$ be the number of valid ways to paint the fence, such it is not true that the last two fenceposts have the same colour.

The number you want is $V_n = A_n+B_n$.

Clearly (or not), $A_0=1$ and $B_0=0$, and therefore $V_0=1$. Also clearly, $V_1=k$. [If you can't convince yourself of this, you can use all my reasoning below, but use $A_2=k^2-k$ and $B_2=k$ in the place I use $A_0=1$ and $B_0=0$.]

Suppose we know $A_{n-1}$ and $B_{n-1}$, and we want $A_n$ and $B_n$.

- Well, $A_n = (k-1)A_{n-1} + (k-1)B_{n-1}$. A fence counted in $A_n$ must be built from either a fence in $A_{n-1}$ or $B_{n-1}$ by painting the $n$th post a different colour from the $(n-1)$th.
- On the other hand, $B_n=A_{n-1}$. To make the last two posts the same colour, we only have one choice of colour to paint the $n$th post. But we can't start with a fence counted in $B_{n-1}$, that would give three posts in a row the same, which is invalid.

So we have

- $A_n=(k-1)[A_{n-1} + B_{n-1}]=(k-1)V_{n-1}$
- $B_n=A_{n-1}=(k-1)V_{n-2}$.
- Therefore, $V_n=A_n+B_n=(k-1)V_{n-1}+(k-1)V_{n-2}$.

Or, $$V_n - (k-1)V_{n-1} - (k-1)V_{n-2}=0$$

Since you already know $A_0$ and $B_0$ and therefore $V_0$ and $V_1$, this is enough to solve it as a coding exercise.

But we can get an explicit formula for $V_n$:

This kind of equation is called a difference equation (Note that if $k=2$ this is the formula for the Fibonacci numbers). One way to solve it is to guess that the solution might be $V_n = x^n$, substitute that into the equation, do some algebra, and get an equation for $x$ called the "characteristic equation":

$$ x^2 - (k-1)x - (k-1) = 0$$

That gives $$x=\frac{k-1\pm\sqrt{k^2+2k-3}}{2},$$ let's say $x = x_1$ or $x_2$, and the solution is

$V_n=C x_1^n + D x_2^n$

where $C$ and $D$ are unknown constants, that can be found using the known values of $V_0$ and $V_1$:

- $V_0=1=C+D$
- $V_1=k=Cx_1+Dx_2$
- Therefore, $C=\frac{x_2-k}{x_2-x_1}$ and $D=\frac{k-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$
- And so: $$V_n=\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}\left((x_2-k)x_1^n+(k-x_1)x_2^n\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the exceptional answer, it was extremely helpful! I even laughed at this line. “The easiest way to count invalid combinations is, ironically, to count valid ones and subtract from n”. My luck that my intuition points down the harder path. 

Anyway, It took a while to sink in for me, but it was so well written and there were easy places to go back and get my bearings again. After letting it sink in for a bit it just finally clicked. Thanks so much!!! The characteristic equation at the end was just the cherry on top!

Comment: You're welcome, and apologies for the many typos :)